# How to call a function onClick of a directory

Tags: php, html, onclick, directory

i'm trying to make a file browser and i'm trying to find how to call a function when the user clicks on a directory. For starting i tried to use onClick inside a href on the class part (right before FUNCTION folderSize) having us a goal to open the path inside testDir if i click on any of the files or directories on the list but it does nothing. I'm searching for some hours now it but i can't find the solution. If someone could help i would be greatfull. 
Here is the index.php:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="/css/myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/dit.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/button2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/resolutionfinder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/changeInputValue.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ajaxcalls.js"></script>





<body onload='ShowDivInCenter();' onresize='ShowDivInCenter();'>

<div class="cont">
<div id="main">


        </script>
  <div id="container">

       <h1> UOP Directory Contents</h1>

    <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.jpg" title="uop search engine" width="450" height="240" />
    <form action=''>
    <input type='search' id="search" name='s' autocomplete="off">

    <input type='button' id="button" value='Search' class="button1" >
    </form>
    <div class="tfclear"></div>
    </div>

    <table class="sortable">
      <thead>

        <tr>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size <small>(KB)</small></th>
          <th>Date Modified</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


<?php

    // Opens directory
    $rootDirectory=opendir(".");
    starter($rootDirectory);
    Function starter($myDirectory)
    {
        $testDir = 'C:\webdev\apache\htdocs\allo1';
        // Gets each entry
        while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) 
        {
          $dirArray[]=$entryName;
        }

        // Finds extensions of files
        function findexts ($filename) 
        {
          $filename=strtolower($filename);
          $exts=split("[/\\.]", $filename);
          $n=count($exts)-1;
          $exts=$exts[$n];
          return $exts;
        }

        // Closes directory
        closedir($myDirectory);

        // Counts elements in array
        $indexCount=count($dirArray);

        // Sorts files
        sort($dirArray);

        // Loops through the array of files
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
        {

          // Allows ./?hidden to show hidden files
          if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
          {$hide="";
          $ahref="./";
          $atext="Hide";}
          else
          {$hide=".";
          $ahref="./?hidden";
          $atext="Show";}
          if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != $hide) {

          // Gets File Names
          $name=$dirArray[$index];
          $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

          // Gets Extensions 
          $extn=findexts($dirArray[$index]); 

          // Gets file size 
          $size=number_format(filesize($dirArray[$index])/1024,2). ' KB';


          // Gets Date Modified Data
          $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
          $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));

          // Prettifies File Types, add more to suit your needs.
          switch ($extn){
            case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
            case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
            case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
            case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
            case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;

            case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
            case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
            case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
            case "js": $extn="Javascript"; break;
            case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;
            case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;

            case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
            case "bak": $extn="Backup File"; break;

            default: $extn=strtoupper($extn)." File"; break;
          }

          // Separates directories
          if(is_dir($dirArray[$index])) {
            $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;"; 
            $size=folderSize($dirArray[$index]); 
            $size=number_format($size/1024,2). ' KB';
            $class="dir";
          } else {
            $class="file";
          }

          // Cleans up . and .. directories 
          if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
          if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}

          // Print 'em
          print("
          <tr class='$class'>
            <td><a href='#' onclick="call_php_function('./$namehref')">$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick="call_php_function('./$namehref')">$extn</a></td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick="call_php_function('./$namehref')">$size</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='#' onclick="call_php_function('./$namehref')">$modtime</a></td>
          </tr>");
          }
        }
    }

FUNCTION call_php_function(directory) 
{
  $.post("index.php", ("dir": directory), function(data){
    alert(data); // Will output, whatever your starter-functions outputs
  });
}

FUNCTION folderSize($dir)
{
$count_size = 0;
$count = 0;
$dir_array = scandir($dir);
  foreach($dir_array as $key=>$filename){
    if($filename!=".." && $filename!="."){
       if(is_dir($dir."/".$filename)){
          $new_foldersize = foldersize($dir."/".$filename);
          $count_size = $count_size+ $new_foldersize;
        }else if(is_file($dir."/".$filename)){
          $count_size = $count_size + filesize($dir."/".$filename);
          $count++;
        }
   }
 }
return $count_size;
}


?>







    <div id="ajaxresults" class="ajaxresults"></div>
<br />
<br />
<hr class="style-seven">

<br />
<br />
<div id="showing"></div>
<div id="results" class="results"></div>

    </tbody>
    </table>

    <form><input type='button' id="button" value='DownLoadAll' class="button2"onClick="window.location.href='downloadZip.php?directtozip=$myDirectory&zipaki'"></form> 



</div>

</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Can we see the starter javascript function? Also.... you may need to treat the $testDir as string by enclosing them in quotes.

Comment: You are mixing server side and client side. Client side onClick cannot and does not call the service side functions.

Answer (score 1):

***Please Notice, that this code is not suitable for public productive use. It's good enough to learn with it.***

The HTML-Part:

```
<a href="#" onclick="call_php_function('any_php_function', 'anyattribut')">Directory-Name</a>
```

The jQuery (Js) Part:

```
function call_php_function(php_function, anyattribut) {
  $.post("functions.php", ("call_function": php_function, "attribute_name": anyattribut), function (data) {
    // Data is what you get from the echo in the PHP-Script below
    alert(data); // Outputs "hello"
  }
}
```

The PHP-Part:

```
function any_php_function($attribut) {
  echo "hello";
}

$allowed_funcs = array("any_php_function", "any_other_function");
if (in_array($_POST["call_function"], $allowed_funcs))
  call_user_func($_POST["attribute_name"]);
```

---

This code is enough for your purposes:

HTML-Part:

```
<a href="#" onclick="call_php_function('directory-name')">directory-name</a>
```

jQuery-Part:

```
function call_php_function(directory) {
  $.post("your_file.php", ("dir": directory), function(data){
    alert(data); // Will output, whatever your starter-functions outputs
  });
}
```

PHP-Part

```
if (isset($_POST["dir"]) && !empty($_POST["dir"])) {
  starter($_POST["dir"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've got pretty confused with the things you wrote, i' trying to add them but it doesn't work and for sure i do something wrong. Can you by any chanse give me some more guidance? My goal for now is calling starter($testDir) when someone clicks on anything(pdf,txt,diretory,etc) on the list.

Comment: @captainmonk - It is actually pretty simple.. In the HTML-Part is your file as a link with an attribute named `onclick` and the javascript-function to call. When you call it, it hands parameters over, which you can define first (in this case your file name). The javascript function does nothing else than connecting to your server, hand over the parameters and wait for an answer. I will edit my answer above to make it specific for your case and easier to read.

Comment: Hey, i am trying to add the information you gave me (i've edited the index with what i've added). I've added the html part in the class(above function call_php_function), i put the jquery part inside index as it is. I can't figure out where to use the php part though. I've got some little knowledge about programming(c java) but i'm new to this staff.

Comment: Can you contact me personally? You can see an e-mail adress in my profile information.